# how to run a web application using specific php version

Tags: php, joomla, hosting

I have a joomla3.0 CMS web application need to be hosted on a web server running php 5.2 which is not compatible with joomla 3.

also i can not update the php on the server because it may affect the other hosted apps.

my question is :

Is it possible to configure the server to run that application only using updated php ? if yes, how ?

Comment: It's a very complex server administration task. If you don't know anything about server administration, you should probably not try it on a live server. The easiest way might be to get a different server/hosting package for the app

Comment: Wouldn't this by more suited for the Server Fault site? I'm not too sure how broad the focus is for SO. It's more about coding than admin stuff like this, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some PHP hosts will run multiple versions of PHP at the same time, and allow you to choose between them either in a global configuration somewhere or in a .htaccess file for specific directories. If it's the latter, then this is simple. I suggest you contact your host and ask them if that is a possibility. - If it's not, then you are likely out of luck. It would be easiest to just host it separately. Supporting sites that require outdated PHP versions is a pain

Comment: i think i am out of luck :) they provide only one version